# Show container on second click

Tags: jquery, html

I am using css to flip a container when clicked.

I am trying to get JQuery to enlarge the back side of the container `once flipped` and `hide all other` containers on the page.

When the container is `clicked again` I want it to `return to normal` (showing all containers again).

This is as far as I have got with my code.

```
$('.f1_container').click(function(event) {
  $('.f1_container').toggleClass('active').width(320).height(400);}).click(function(){
    $('.f2_container,.f3_container,.f4_container,.f5_container,.f6_container').hide();
  });
```

My problem is when I click the second time all hidden containers stay hidden.

Here is my **HTML**.

```
<div class="f1_container">
  <div class="shadow f1_card">
    <div class="front face">
      <img src="images/y1.jpg" style="height: 160px; width: 160px;">
    </div>
    <div class="back face center">
      Some text inside here
    </div>
   </div><!-- end of shadow f1_card -->
</div><!-- end of f1_container -->

<div class="f2_container">
  <div class="shadow f2_card">
    <div class="front face">
      <img src="images/o1a.jpg" style="height: 160px; width: 160px;">
    </div>
    <div class="back face center">
      Some text inside here
    </div>
  </div><!-- end of shadow f2_card -->
</div><!-- end of f2_container -->

<div class="f3_container">
  <div class="shadow f3_card">
    <div class="front face">
      <img src="images/o1a.jpg" style="height: 160px; width: 160px;">
    </div>
    <div class="back face center">
      Some text inside here
    </div>
  </div><!-- end of shadow f3_card -->
</div><!-- end of f3_container -->
```

Comment: use .toggle() ? (http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Please provide your HTML code aswell, otherwise its very hard to understand what you are trying to achiv and how your elements /classes are called and structured. Its also helpful if you made misstakes here...

Comment: Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrektshy/) to see how it can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you really want this function to work on all containers without having to specific a ton of different handlers for each, we can use jQuery's `attribute ends with selector ($)`. We can compare against any class that ends with `_container`. We also use `.not` to ensure we don't toggle the visibility of the container that we clicked on.

```
$('*[class$="_container"]').click(function(){ 
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('*[class$="_container"]').not(this).toggle();
});
```

In your CSS fie, ensure the active class contains the width/height constraints:

```
.active{
    width: 320px;
    height:400px;
}
```

Comment: Good point with `[class$="_container"]`, but this will not get clicked element size back to normal one on second click. Also there are some places to simplify: `$('[class$="_container"]')` and `.not(this)`.

Comment: @Regent Yea, it's true, the width/height should be CSS defined, I was just moving quickly with copy pasta. :)

Comment: Even though unnecessary `*` is still in `$('*[class$="_container"]')`, it's definitely +1 :)